# Can we replace dockerfile by docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, command, dockerfile

Maybe I didn't understand well Docker but I don't see the point making a Dockerfile **for my use**.
in compose I can specify almost everything I need to set in my dockerfile except two points :

1) I didn't find the equivalent for COPY/ADD into docker-compose.yml so I'm using directory but it's making the image from the host. What is the difference between copy and add ? Is it possible to implement it from the docker-compose file ?

2) I didn't find the equivalent for RUN. I'm using a node script so I need to NPM install like you would do with a RUN in dockerfile. The way I found is to set "npm install && node server.js" in the start command of my package.json file. Is there a better way to do it ? Maybe into the command field ?

I'm not very good with English so don't hesitate to ask for precisions. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: No, Dockerfile instructs Docker how to _build_ your image(s). Docker Compose instructs Docker how to _run_ your image(s).

Comment: Thx, so I have to make a dockerfile just to have the copy command ? What is the difference between copy and add in dockerfile ?

Comment: `ADD` does a similar thing with side-effects in some cases. If you don't know that you need `ADD`, use `COPY`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1) [Here are the official docs between COPY and ADD](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy):

> Although ADD and COPY are functionally similar, generally speaking,
>   COPY is preferred. That’s because it’s more transparent than ADD. COPY
>   only supports the basic copying of local files into the container,
>   while ADD has some features (like local-only tar extraction and remote
>   URL support) that are not immediately obvious. Consequently, the best
>   use for ADD is local tar file auto-extraction into the image, as in
>   ADD rootfs.tar.xz /.

You **can't** do this in a docker-compose.yml, you'd have to use a Dockerfile if you want to add files to the image.

2) docker-compose.yml has both an entrypoint and command override. Similar to how you'd pass a `CMD` at runtime with docker, you can do with a `docker-compose run`

`docker run -itd mystuff/myimage:latest bash -c 'npm install && node server.js'`

You can do this with `docker-compose`, assuming the service name here is myservice:

`docker-compose run myservice bash -c 'npm install && node server.js'`

---

If your use case is only running one container, it's probably hard to see the benefits of docker-compose as a beginner. If you were to add a mongodb an nginx container to your dev stack you'd start to see where docker-compose *really* picks up and gives you benefits. It works best when used to orchestrate several containers that need to run and communicate with each other.

Comment: Loud and clear ! Now I understand better. Sorry can't vote + yet :S. I'm using two Node containers (auth+api) and one Mongo so I use compose and see well why. thx